# Cypress: custom command - how to get input field value

Tags: typescript, cypress

I need to get value of input[text] element inside of custom command.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('extendValue', {
    prevSubject: 'element'
}, (subject: JQuery<HTMLElement>, extension: string): any => {
    const res = cy.wrap(subject);
    const t1 = res.invoke('val'); // here it doesn't work
    console.log(t1)
    res.type(extension);
    return res;
});
```

Comment: Can you add an example of the HTML?

Comment: It looks like you can use Cypress commands to replace what you are trying to do.

Comment: Cypress commands always return a Chainer, but you will have already seen this in the console. Why do you want the current value? It does not help your custom command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the existing value, don't wrap it

```js
const currentVal = subject.val();
```

Note, subject is an input so

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('extendValue', {prevSubject: 'element'}, (
  subject: JQuery<HTMLInputElement>, 
  extension: string): Chainer<HTMLInputElement> => {
  ...
```